# setting a custom post type taxonomy term by code

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, terms

I have a set of radio buttons on my metabox which looks like

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <label class="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="r3" value="15"> No</label>
  <label class="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="r3" value="17"> Maybet</label>
  <label class="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="r3" value="16"> Yes</label>
</div>
```

and I need to call a WordPress function like this on publish or update event happened (based on radios states)

```
<?php wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term, $taxonomy) ?>
```

can you please let me know if I can do this in core PHP without using any js? or javascript world how can I pass value from radios to wp_set_post_terms() function?

```
$('input:radio[name=r3]').on('change', function() {
  var val = $('input:radio[name=r3]:checked').val();
  switch (val) {
    case '15':
      //
      break;
    case '16':
      //
      break;
       case '17':
      //
      break;   
  }
});
```

> Update

I find this code on the web

```
  $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix .'term_relationships', array('object_id'=>$post_id, 'term_taxonomy_id'=>$_POST['term'], 'term_order'=>'0'));
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864008/wordpress-add-custom-taxonomy-to-a-page-programmatically) but can someone please let me know how to pass values from the radios `$_POST['term']` to the `$wpdb->insert()` properly?

Comment: Are you sure that "Yes", "Maybe" and "No" are taxonomy terms? Also, to achieve your goal you don't need JavaScript at all.

Comment: Hi Max, Yes I am sure they are terms and the `[15, 16, 17]` are the term_id that I got them from WP. Can you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: Can you please take a look at the updated in the post, thanks